# I have firebase cloud function that working final when request from Postman, but I get error when request from flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have tried to send request from Advanced REST client it's working perfectly,
but from flutter is not working.

firebase function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const quantity = 'quantity';
const colors = 'colors';
const price = 'price';
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addProductQuantity = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const ii = request.get('count');
    const id = request.get('product_id');
    const promise = db.collection(colors).doc(id).get();
    const p2 = promise.then(snapshot => {

        var newVal = snapshot.get(quantity);
        newVal = Number(newVal) + Number(ii); 
        db.collection(colors).doc(id).update({
            quantity: newVal
        });
        return response.status(200).send('OK '+newVal);
    });
    p2.catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return response.status(500).send(error.data);
    });
});
```

Flutter code

```
  static Future addProductQuantity(Product product) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = Map();
    map["product_id"] = "d0001";
    map["count"] = 25;

    final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance
        .getHttpsCallable(functionName: "addProductQuantity");

    try {
      dynamic resp = await callable.call(map);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Cloud Function Error: $e");
    }
  }
```

error from firebase function log

```
    addProductQuantity
     Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
        at Object.validateResourcePath (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:403:15)
        at CollectionReference.doc (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1718:20)
        at exports.addProductQuantity.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:13:43)
        at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
        at /worker/worker.js:783:7
        at /worker/worker.js:766:11
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

I have tried with the same `product_id` in ARC it's worked fine

Comment: I have the same issue, any luck?

Comment: I updated my flutter and firebase it resolves my issues

Comment: Have anyone solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, while testing using postman I was passing `raw` data and then performing `jsonEncode` in the cloud function.
And the problem occurred when, I was passing `jsonEncoded` data in Flutter.

**So, I was actually performing *jsonEncode twice* and that was creating an issue.
Just remove jsonEncode from cloud function.**